# How do I get rails Xeroizer Gem contacts = xero.Contact.all(:where => 'Name.Contains("Peter")') to work on interpolated values

Tags: ruby

The Rails Xeroizer documentation lists the following query method

```
contacts = xero.Contact.all(:where => 'Name.Contains("Peter")')
```

below works but is not very useful

```
@xero_suppliers = @xero_client.Contact.all(:where => 'Name.StartsWith("N")')
```

This

```
@xero_suppliers_does_not_work = @xero_client.Contact.all(:where => supplier_name )
```

results in

> "QueryParseException: No applicable method 'startsWith' exists in type >'String' 
>   Generated by the following XML: 
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
>    16

this

```
@xero_suppliers_does_not_work = @xero_client.Contact.all(:where => Name.StartsWith(@supplier.name[0..0]))
```

results in

> uninitialized constant AccountingController::Name

this

```
@xero_suppliers_does_not_work = @xero_client.Contact.all(:where => "Name.startsWith(\'#{@supplier.name[0..0]}\')" )
```

results in

> QueryParseException: No applicable method 'startsWith' exists in type 'String' 
>   Generated by the following XML: 
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
>    16

Comment: When you say "doesn't work" what's the error?  Is it supposed to be  `startsWith` or `StartsWith`? You don't need to escape single quotes in your `supplier_name` variable's string.

Comment: Hi Simone,\@xero_suppliers_does_not_work = @xero_client.Contact.all(:where => Name.StartsWith(@supplier.name[0..0]))\uninitialized constant AccountingController::Name

Answer (score 0):

Your working example holds the correct syntax, so you should continue to use it:

```
@xero_suppliers = @xero_client.Contact.all(:where => 'Name.StartsWith("N")')
```

It seems like you want to make the `"N"` part dynamic.

```
@xero_suppliers = @xero_client.Contact.all(:where => "Name.StartsWith(\"#{@supplier.name[0]}\")")
```

This should produce output identical to your first query. You are getting errors in the other cases because you are either referring to the constant `Name` (no quotes) or you are mistyping "StartsWith" as "startsWith".